# October CMS - Tailor detail page twig not loop post slug

Tags: content-management-system, octobercms, blueprint

I have news and news detail page. But i can’t get detail page link. What is my wrong? Also I can’t open manually news detail page through direct link.

I need community help immidently. [image]

[image]

I changed code on list page . `{{ 'news'|page({slug: post.slug}) }}`

I added entrySlug = `"{{ :slug }}"` on detail page.
but nothing changed.

I added detail page link on description area on the news list page for show clearly. Result is still same…

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use page file name with the `|page` filter.

```html
{{ 'news-detail'|page({slug: post.slug}) }}
```

> as `|page` works with the page `file name` and not with the `slug`.

I guess this should solve your issue.

if you have any doubts please comment